# How can I run my own java code in the JVM that I am debugging remotely with JDWP?

Tags: java, eclipse, remote-debugging, penetration-testing, jdwp

As a penetration tester, I have come across an open JDWP port. I can connect to it with Eclipse and browse the threads and memory, but I don't have the source code for the application. I'd like to inject my own Java code, perhaps as an Exception handler, in order to return a shell. How can I modify the running/suspended Java application over JDWP, preferably using Eclipse as my debugger?

Comment: Um, isn't that your job to figure out?

Comment: @user1183387:I was wondering why do you want to do that?An open port either for remote debugging or for remote management via JMX in the field is a finding by itself.I.e. it should be closed.So why are you trying to do an exploit?Just report it as a finding.

Comment: @bmargulies Congratulations, you have found the universal comment that can be applied to every question on stackoverflow.

Comment: @user384706 If the test were a vulnerability scan, then yes. As part of a penetration test, though, I want to exploit the vulnerability to gain privileges on the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my question: [JavaPayload](http://schierlm.users.sourceforge.net/JavaPayload/) by Michael 'mihi' Schierl lets you load Java payloads through JDWP, among others.