# I am unable to setup remote debugging for my Tomcat 6 web app on Ubuntu 12.04, can anyone help me?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat6, remote-debugging, iptables, nmap

I am unable to setup remote debugging for my Tomcat 6 web app on Ubuntu 12.04.

I have tried the solutions offered in the following related question:
[Remote debugging Tomcat with Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835612/remote-debugging-tomcat-with-eclipse)

The highest ranked solution says I should open catalina.sh and change the JPDA_OPTS variable to:
    JPDA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"

Then start tomcat using jpda:
catalina.sh jpda start

I checked my app at localhost, port 8000 and got an 'Unable to connect error'.

The next best solution was:

In catalina.bat file please modify the below.

```
Step 1: CATALINA_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"

Step 2: JPDA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"

Step 3: Run Tomcat from command prompt like below: catalina.sh jpda start
```

When I checked localhost, port 8000 I got the same 'Unable to connect error'.
Attempting to connect to the tomcat debugger through Eclipse after both of these
attempts gave me an error:

```
Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.
Connection refused
```

This made me think that port 8000 might be closed so I ran an nmap command to show
which ports on my 'localhost' were open. It returned the following:

```
ryan@ryan-K53E:~$ nmap -v localhost

Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-04-15 22:12 BST
Initiating Ping Scan at 22:12
Scanning localhost (127.0.0.1) [2 ports]
Completed Ping Scan at 22:12, 0.00s elapsed (1 total hosts)
Initiating Connect Scan at 22:12
Scanning localhost (127.0.0.1) [1000 ports]
Discovered open port 80/tcp on 127.0.0.1
Discovered open port 3306/tcp on 127.0.0.1
Discovered open port 53/tcp on 127.0.0.1
Discovered open port 22/tcp on 127.0.0.1
Discovered open port 8080/tcp on 127.0.0.1
Discovered open port 631/tcp on 127.0.0.1
Completed Connect Scan at 22:12, 0.02s elapsed (1000 total ports)
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00028s latency).
Not shown: 994 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
53/tcp   open  domain
80/tcp   open  http
631/tcp  open  ipp
3306/tcp open  mysql
8080/tcp open  http-proxy

Read data files from: /usr/share/nmap
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.07 seconds
```

This looks to confirm that port 8000 is closed so I defined 'tomcat-debug' as a service in the 
'/etc/services' file like so:

```
tomcat-debug        8000/tcp        # Remote tomcat debugging
```

Then tried to open port 8000 with iptables using the following command:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport tomcat-debug -j ACCEPT
```

This doesn't seem to have made a difference as nmap is still showing the same list of open ports as 
before. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that JDWP is a dangerous thing to expose. http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/jdwp-exec.html and http://stackoverflow.com/a/9200263/1183387

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I don't think the port is open according to my nmap output, do you think it is?

Comment: No, it does not look open, but you intend to open it. Just make sure there are other controls in place (like a source IP restriction in your iptables rule) to prevent others from accessing it. I think the debugger can be opened in client mode, too (meaning you have a debugger listening for the incoming connection). To avoid the complete Nmap scan every time, use -p 8000

Answer (score 1):

Before checking if port 8000 is reachable form outside (your test with nmap) , have you tried to check if tomcat is listening on port 8000 ?

I'd use  `sudo netstat -pnl | grep 8000`  to get a list of all process listening on port and filter this list for lines containing 8000.
you should receive something like this :

`tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      14236/java`

This line tell that the process java (pid 14236) is listening for tcp on **localhost**(127.0.0.1) port **8000**.

You should check that you tomcat process is listening on an external address if you want to connect to  from external.

Comment: I'm having the same problem as the OP. In my case there is nothing listening on port 8000, and I have no idea why.